# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier in Select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error in my select query - here is my scenario:

Table 1

```
EntityId int, 
ItemId nvarchar(40)
```

Table 2

```
Id uniqueidentifier,
Desc nvarchar(250), 
EntityId int,
Rate decimal(18,2)
```

I write following query:

```
Select Table2.Rate
From Table1
Inner Join Table2
        on Table1.EntityId = Table2.EntityId
```

I get the error "Conversion failed from character to uniqueidentifier".
I am not using `Table2.Id` column anywhere in my query still the error.

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem at [sqlfidde](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Are you sure that that's the query you are using and the right data types for each column?

Comment: Change your "SELECT Table2.Rate" to "SELECT 1" and leave the rest of the query the same.  Do you still get the same error?  Also, are both tables or is one a view?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your above query in sqlfiddle below and returns no error:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (EntityId int, ItemId nvarchar(40))

CREATE TABLE table2 (Id uniqueidentifier,
[Desc] nvarchar(250), 
EntityId int,
Rate decimal(18,2))

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'N0394')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2,'N9495')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3,'N0590')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4,'N5250')


INSERT INTO table2([Desc],EntityId,Rate) VALUES ('Desc1',1,12.00)
INSERT INTO table2([Desc],EntityId,Rate) VALUES ('Desc2',2,55.00)
INSERT INTO table2([Desc],EntityId,Rate) VALUES ('Desc3',3,60.00)
INSERT INTO table2([Desc],EntityId,Rate) VALUES ('Desc4',4,75.00)

--Query to find rates
Select Table2.Rate
From Table1
Inner Join Table2
        on Table1.EntityId = Table2.EntityId
```

[Click Here for DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4889/1/0)